# Implement a slot machine-like animation using Framer Motion

Tags: framer-motion

I'm trying to implement a vertical carousel or slot machine-like animation using the Framer Motion library.  The sentence is 'Automate your ' and the rotating word is just a string inside an array.  It seems easy enough and I've looked at the carousel example in the Framer Motion docs, but I keep running into flickering and weird layout effects.  I want nothing to move except for the word that infinitely rotates.  If you take a look at the linked [CodePen](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-image-gallery-forked-wh9qrs?file=/src/Example.tsx:492-725), the word should appear from beneath like a reversed slot machine every 2 seconds.  Not sure what I'm missing and I don't have much experience with Framer, so I'm running into a wall here.